# SKAction playSoundFileNamed doesn't work after receiving two consecutive phone calls

Tags: ios, objective-c, audio, sprite-kit, skaction

I am trying to figure out why ***playSoundFileNamed*** doesn't work after receiving two consecutive phone calls. Actually it works only after the first phone call is received. Reproducing steps are:

1. Start a game
2. Wait for a phone call and go to background
3. Phone call is finished (declined or interrupted by caller)
4. Returning to foreground

After this, playing the sound from ***touchesBegan*** still works.

When I repeat the steps from above (first step is skipped), mechanism from touchesBegan stops working. Not sure why is this happening...Here is the code which can produce described behaviour:

```
@interface GameScene()

@property (nonatomic, strong) SKAction *sound;
@end

@implementation GameScene

-(void)didMoveToView:(SKView *)view {
    self.sound = [SKAction playSoundFileNamed:@"sound1.wav" waitForCompletion:NO];
}

-(void)touchesBegan:(NSSet *)touches withEvent:(UIEvent *)event {
    /* Called when a touch begins */
    [self runAction:self.sound];
}
@end
```

I know there are some questions related to this on SO, but given answers are related to workarounds. **I am not interested in workaround, but rather why is this happening?** Is it somehow related to AVAudioSession ? (probably not) I know I could use AVAudioPlayer as a workaround, but still not sure how much is that performant for playing a lot of simple short sounds...

Comment: I was dealing with this quite a while ago.  I never found a solution.  For me it would only take one phone call though.  But there was a worse situation that you may want to check for also.  I was using iAd and every time an ad that had sound (like those game of war ads) was presented, this too would stop playSoundFileNamed: from working until the app was relaunched.  The only thing I could do was remove ads from my game.  I couldn't risk the user experience of having all the game sound effects fail if they happened to get an ad with audio.  And I had to just hope users don't get a call.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The SKAction `playSoundFileNamed` is buggy in regards to the app transitioning between background and foreground. That's the reason why you are having this issue. I am not sure if this problem has been corrected in iOS 9.

As for a workaround, you stated you're not interest but I will include one for completion's sake. Use AVAudioPlayer instead of SKAction. AVAP has the ability to stop and start (using its delegates) based on your app's state.

Comment: Yeah, playSoundFileNamed acts buggy and probably at the moment of speaking we can't do anything to change that. I guess I could fill a radar about this.

Answer (score 0):

This could be an issue with mixed audio. I've found that enabling mixed audio no longer stops SpriteKit's audio engine during an interruption, ad video playing, or app backgrounding.

```
try? AVAudioSession.sharedInstance().setCategory(AVAudioSessionCategoryAmbient)
```

Comment: neave - I tried your solution and just tested, but it didn't work for me.  There is a lot of info on this subject but it is very dated.  Is this still working for your app?  I can't switch - whenever I go to other sound engines, run into a performance issue.  Thanks for any info